# How to exclude files from chown recursive using wildcard in file name?

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, rhel7

I want to run `chown` recursively on a folder, but I don't want to include files named `"ssl.cert.webmintmp.26599"` or `"ssl.cert.webmintmp.356849"`, so I need to replace the number at the end by a wildcard character. And also the folder before that file should be a wildcard since there are several different folder names.

I've tried running:

```
sudo chown -R user:apache /home/ !({ssl.cert.**,**/ssl.cert.**})
```

By what I found on this question which didn't work; ([How do I exclude a folder when performing file operations i.e. cp, mv, rm and chown etc. in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065447/how-do-i-exclude-a-folder-when-performing-file-operations-i-e-cp-mv-rm-and-ch))

As I get errors;

```
./chowntest.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./chowntest.sh: line 2: `sudo chown -R user:apache /home/ !({ssl.cert.**,**/ssl.cert.**})'
```

Is this doable?

Comment: Have you considered running `find ... -exec chown ...`?

Comment: `chown -R` simply recurses the directori(es) you pass as arguments; there is no exclusion facility. I'll second the suggestion to use `find` instead.

Comment: The error message looks like you didn't enable `extglob` but it won't help with `chown -R` anyway.

Comment: the `find` command seems to take considerably longer than the `chown`, that was the reason as to why I was wondering if it was even possible to do without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chown -R` does not perform any interpretation of what you pass in. Any attempts to use things like `!(...)` are interpreted by the shell. If you want to support fancy logic in your recursion, use something like `find`:

```
find /home ! -name 'ssl.cert.*' -exec chown user:apache '{}' \;
```